# Alternative to deprecated exists() function in AngularFire2 (rc5.0)

Tags: angularfire2, angularfire5

I just updated to latest version of AngularFire2 rc5.

It looks like `exist()` does not exist anymore.

Do you know what's the new way to check if the snapshot exists ?

Comment: i believe `$exist()` still exist, don't mentioned in any docs. and its a `firebase.database.DataSnapshot` feature.

Comment: I used `.snapshotChanges()` which is supposed to preserve the snapshot but when I call `.exists()` (sorry btw, I initially wrote it with a $) and this returns an error. When I inspect the snapshot, the exists function seems not to be present...

Comment: i think you need a `.forEach` also to get the children of a DataSnapshot.